# Even more about Galois Fields

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

Here's one interesting question that I found in my textbook. But first, here's some background information:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, and $P(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z_p}$. Let deg $P = v$. Let $F = GF(p,P(x))$ be the corresponding Galois field and notice that $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is a *subfield* of $F$.

Here's is what I need to show:

> Show that, for any element $a$ of $F$, $a^p = a$ *if anf only if* $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

First of all, I don't like how this question if phrased. I prefer to use the notation $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ instead of $GF(p,P(x))$. I've been collaborating with the people in my math class on how to solve this problem, but haven't gotten far. I defined $P(x)$ to be a *non-zero* polynomial such that $$P(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ a_2x^2 + ... + a_{v-1}x^{v-1}$$

$\Rightarrow$ Rough sketch is the use Fermat's Little Theorem.

$\Leftarrow$ I believe that the fact that $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is a *subfield* of $F$ should be considered here.

That's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: $x^p-x$ has at most $p$ roots. Since these are exactly the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, there are no other roots.

Comment: Sort of a side issue, but since you brought it up... $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is often used for the (infinite) field of $p$-adic numbers, which is why some people don't like to use it for the finite field with $p$ elements. But the finite field (or the cyclic group) shows up *all over the place* in math, while the $p$-adics are not nearly as wide-spread. So in many contexts, I don't think the shorter notation for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is such a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $a \mapsto a^p$ is important in the study of finite fields.  For more information, you can Google "Frobenius endomorphism".  The reason this is interesting is that composing $a \mapsto a^p$ with itself over and over will generate the entire automorphism group of the finite field of order $p^n$.  Indeed, Galois groups of finite fields are cyclic.  Anyways...

You have the right idea about the forward direction.  If we think group-theoretically, $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is a group under multiplication of order $p-1$.  Therefore, $a^{p-1} = 1$ as a consequence of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), which gives $a^p = a$ (this is essentially just a re-proof of FLT).  Of course this is also true for $0$, so we have $a^p = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

For the converse, Crostul in the comments has the right idea.  Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^p - x$.  By the above, all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ satisfies this polynomial, and the number of roots of a polynomial over a field (counting multiplicity) is always equal to the degree of that polynomial.

Comment: I like your proof, but instead of using $f(x)$, can we use $P(x)$, or is this just another separate function that you defined?

Comment: It's a separate one @i8Σπ_821.  The $f$ here works to make the same argument for any finite field of characteristic $p$, whereas the $P$ you refer to is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ -- which you use to build the degree $n$ field extension over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Ahh now I understand.